# Banshee Amazon MP3 Integration Broken

Tags: banshee, mp3-player, amazon-mp3-downloader

Amazon have introduced their new Amazon Cloud Player, bang goes Banshee's Amazon MP3 download support. It really was an iTunes killer for me, but hey life sucks.

Will Banshee Support The New Amazon Site?

Do the dev's have anything up their sleeves?  Or are their hands tied?

Comment: Workaround [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/197409/63478).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is something you would be best asking the developers themselves. http://banshee.fm/

Comment: Shoulda thought of that...